# Make Gradle use local Groovy/Scala

Tags: scala, groovy, gradle, build.gradle

Assume I have Groovy installed in `/path/to/groovy/{bin,lib,...}` or Scala `/path/to/scala/{bin,lib,...}`.
Can I make Gradle use these executables and libraries in dependency management and building the project, instead of downloading Groovy/Scala from the web?

To make it clear, I'm talking about informal private projects, which do not need to be shared with anyone else (hence, hard-coding paths is not an issue). The only reasons behind it are avoiding redundant JARs and that I like to (micro-)manage local Groovy/Scala manually.

Alternatively, if this is a really bad idea even for private development, can someone explain why?

Comment: What do you hope to gain from this? Saving a few MB of disk space is not worth the hassle.

Comment: What's wrong with `compile "org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:x.y.z"`?

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser, so I presume it _is_ a really bad idea. Am I the first one who came up with it? Could you please add an answer, so that I can accept it and deter all the future micro-managers?

I didn't expect any huge gain, just a little bit more control: I'm mostly programming in the small, so I'm used to using all things local, and I was suprised I couldn't do it with Gradle.

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser Although I would expect compiler hackers to be interested in something along these lines, but they are different beasts altogether.

Comment: I think the main concern here is, that why do you want to use something like gradle to deal with your deps and then do it on your own.  If you are developing local stuff, this is some other story.  Maybe [Gradles file deps](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#file-dependencies) helps?

Comment: It can be done, but I'd only do it if I had a very concrete reason to.

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser Got it! In fact, I didn't have any strong motives to do it; I was just wondering.